# Why does IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 show sbt files with so many lines in red?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I had a working sbt based project. After some small change that I can not specifically identify all the sbt files are having object resolution issues (see screenshots).

I tried the following:

- sbt refresh
- project rebuild
- reimport project

These did not work.

Then I started going farther afield to resolve the issue.  I copied the *.sbt files *from another project* on top of the ones in this project.  **Still no dice**.    Now I do not have time presently to actually completely destroy, rebuild the project from scratch - and in any case that does not lead to any insight on the root cause here.

Has anyone experienced this issue - and any suggestions on remedies/workarounds?

**Update**  I finally tried

sbt gen-idea

even though this project was **not ** built that way..  It did make a difference: at least the crazy errors went away. But now a different set of problems arises: the assembly and packaging imports are not being resolved (see LAST screenshot).  But this seems *a bit* more healthy at least .

[image]

[image]

Following screenshot is after running **sbt gen-idea.**  Situation has improved but now get assembly/packaging import errors.

[image]

**Another update**
OK, I have quit and restarted IJ and things are finally back. 
So the objective changes that I made:

- sbt gen-idea
- stop/restart IJ

This is feeling like magic incantations here .. Not a solid process.

Comment: BTW, I can notice you use `seq(assemblySettings: _*)` while `assemblySettings` alone's enough.

Comment: Why do you use sbt gen-idea plugin? I am trying to understand whether only idea plugins (Scala and sbt) are enough to import a project from sbt and keep working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sort of a workaround could be to upgrade to the latest EAP of [IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3 build 135.909, released on May 23rd, 2014](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP). It comes with more sophisticated Scala plugin that is much clever than the previous versions and hopefully could help here and there.

Comment: Well i will try it out - would have done so anyways. Presently it is giving error can not connect. I will update here when the update succeeds.

Comment: Intellij updates are still not working. i did another sof issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031202/intellij-check-for-updates-unable-to-connect

Comment: intellij updates started working again.  But the problem remains, even with the v latest ij.

Comment: @Jacek Do you know if, with the new Scala plugin, there is any usage for the gen-idea plugin?

Comment: There should be none, but been told that there are some use cases that `sbt-idea` handles better. I don't use `sbt-idea` at all and rely on IDEA only.