# Intellij check for updates: unable to connect

Tags: intellij-idea, updates

The following screenshot has been showing up for several days now.  Are other people seeing this?

Note: to be sure it were not a general connection error, in addition to being able to post this sof message i did a github pull. That is a solid indication that my network proxies have been properly disabled: and it worked fine. So the message is puzzling.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122848#_ga=1.45659684.1475980656.1401867265) fixed in Intellij IDEA 13.1 (27 Mar 2014).

1. Go to Settings / Updates, then press button "Check now".
2. Result: normal Update info.

Un-checking **Use secure connection** in the above mentioned window may fix the issue under some circumstances.

Comment: Huh. I tried again and it did work the second attempt. Awarding.. pls consider upvote.

Comment: Same here on Mac OSX 10.8.5 with ItelliJ 13.1.2: Connection failed.

Comment: I just manually installed IntelliJ 13.1.4, same problem there when checking for updates: Connection failed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, 15.0.2 ultimate, on a VBox VM inside Windows 7 on an intranet. But all connectivity from the VM to the outside world works fine.

Comment: @RaulSantelices **uncheck** `Use secure connection` in settings -> updates

Answer (score 30):

To fix this problem:

- Select Settings / HTTP Proxy
- Select the radio button: **Auto-detect proxy settings** or simply **No proxy**

If select **Auto-detect proxy settings**:

- Select check box for Automatic proxy configuration URL: and enter your proxy URL
- Select Check connection button

Worked for me!

Comment: The prior answer already solved the problem - but your answer seems to provide useful info for others looking here so I will upvote in any case.

Comment: default setting was 'No Proxy' when the error occurred, in my case; 'Auto-detect Proxy' did it for me (while keeping everything as default).

Comment: This answer worked out for me on my windows machine.

Comment: Auto-detect Proxy with no URL worked for me - thx